# Oracle SQL Analytic ordered grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I get most of my application specifics out of the way and get things simplied.
Here's what I start with and where I need to go. I've already tried many, many things with LEAD/LAG function and inner SQL, for example, but I don't seem to get to the point without writing procedural code. Here's the problem:

Given this:

```
with some_data as (select 1 seqnc, to_date('12-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') date_deb, 2 qte_min from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('13-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('14-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('15-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 4 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('16-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 4 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('17-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('18-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('19-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2 from dual union
                   select 1 seqnc, to_date('20-06-2018','dd-mm-yyyy'), 2 from dual)
select * from some_data;
```

Dates are always consecutives. I need to get same values of qte_min grouped by consecutive dates (not a group for all the same value).
I need to end up with something like that:

```
date_deb   qte_min   nbre_jrs
12-06-2018      2           3
15-06-2018      4           2
17-06-2018      2           4
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a difference of row numbers and the date to define the groups:

```
select seqnc, min(date_db), max(date_db), min(qte_min), count(*)
from (select sd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by seqnc order be date_db) as seqnum_d
      from some_data sd
     ) sd
group by seqnc, (date_db - seqnum_d)
```

Comment: It doesn't work exactly as written, but I got the gist and with this little tweak...

`(partition by seqnc, **qte_min** order by date_db)`

it works perfectly. Thanks!